# how to eliminate the horizontal spacing of the frame in the framed package?

Tags: spacing, framed

I'm using the framed package and I found it difficult to adjust the width of a frame to adapt to the current environment, e.g. if I use a `shaded` environment within the `enumerate` environment, I will get a frame box as wide as the current page (actually slightly wider) -- it will not indent accordingly; then I found a solution to make the frame of the same width as the current environment, but a new problem arised: there seems to be extra horizontal spacing inside the frame. A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}
\newenvironment{myframe}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\hsize\linewidth\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
test a frame within an enumerate environment
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item abc
    \begin{myframe}
    def
    \end{myframe}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody tell me how to eliminate the extra left padding so that the content of the frame can align to the list item? Thanks a lot!

A screenshot is here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR1SF.png]

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I tried to answer directly but got a message box, and I thought it recommended me to edit my original post. I will extract the answer out then.

Answer (score 6):

I asked the author of the `framed` package, and his solution worked for me (although I do not really understand it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9}
\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{snugshade}{%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
test a frame within an enumerate environment test a frame within an enumerate environment
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item abc
    \begin{snugshade}
def
    \end{snugshade}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using the **mdframed** package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % better than color
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.9}

\begin{document}
test a frame within an enumerate environment
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item abc
    \begin{mdframed}[
      backgroundcolor=shadecolor,
      leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargin-2pt\relax,
      innerleftmargin=1.6pt,
      innertopmargin=2pt,
      skipabove=3pt,skipbelow=3pt
    ]
    def
    \end{mdframed}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appending  tilde after `\vspace{-4mm}` removes the problem:

```
\item abc \\[-8mm]~
```

or

```
 \item abc \vspace{-4mm}~
```

Here is the complete text

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{framed,color}
  \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.9, .9, .9} 
   \newenvironment{myframe}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \colorbox{shadecolor}}%
  \MakeFramed {\hsize\linewidth\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
  {\endMakeFramed}

  \begin{document}
      test a frame within an enumerate environment
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item abc\\[-8mm]~
    \begin{myframe}
     def
    \end{myframe}
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```